# The "err" argument when using Async waterfall in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-async

I am trying to execute a series of functions, each passing the callback to the next. Right now it looks like this (excuse any minor errors, I am rewriting it as I post!):

```
function func1(callback) {
    callback(null, "stuff");
}

function func2(input, callback) {
    callback(null, "foo" + input);
}

async.waterfall([func1, func2], function(err, result) {
    sys.puts(result);
});
```

My first question is that I'm not sure how to start this function gracefully, since it can't take an input. I'm going to eventually wrap that one in a local function, but it still makes me slightly uneasy.

Secondly, while this works, I have no idea how the "err" argument plays into this. If I try to insert it into the list of arguments, it breaks in various ways. I'd like to be able to catch an error in any function individually - or is this needed, since I have an error on the last callback which is passed down?

Answer (score 17):

Waterfall is normally used with anonymous functions, therefore the parameters come from the outer scope.

How the `err` works is simple, when you supply anything that evaluates to true as the first argument of the callback function waterfall will stop and call the main callback.

```
function doStuff(foo, bla) {
    // more setup here

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            try {
                // something that might explode
                callback(null, foo, bla);

            } catch (e) {
                callback(e);
            }
        },

        function(arg1, arg2, callback){
            callback(null, 'three');
        },

        function(arg1, callback){
            callback(null, 'done');
        }
    ],

    function (err, status) {
       // if the above try/catche catches something, we will end up here
       // otherwise we will receive 'done' as the value of status
       // after the third function has finished
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use async.constant to pass an input to the first function in the chain:

```
async.waterfall([
    async.constant(parameter),
    func1,
    func2
 ], function (err, result) {            
 });
```

and modify the first function of course:

```
function func1(input,callback) {
    callback(null, "stuff");
}
```

Optional: you can call callback with a non-null first parameter:

```
 function func1(input,callback) {
        callback("something");
    }
```

In this case the chain is stopped, and the last function will be called with err="something"

Documentation: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#constant and https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall